# ASP.NET Double buttons displaying?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I'm developing a web application in c# in ASP.NET. I have the following code for my body of the html/aspx document. However, I am getting a very weird result when the page is loaded (see picture). What could cause this?

```
<body>
    <form id="upload" runat="server">
        <div id="upload-controls">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            <p>Select your CCD/XML File: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Load XML/CCD" /><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" />
            <p>Select your XSL File (Leave blank for default): <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Load XSL" /><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
            <p><input type="button" name="viewbutton" value="View" onclick="handleFileSelect()" /></p>
        </div>
        <div id="output">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Picture:

[image: ASPX Double Buton]

Comment: What is weird? It's doing exactly what you tell it to do.

Comment: Do you mean the "Chose File" button? that's there because it's part of the FileUpload control. You don't need to create your own button for it.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that what you are using is Web Forms, a technology under ASP.Net. MVC is also under ASP.Net, so it would be useful if you specified the WebForms tag on this one (and removed it from the title since it would be redundant).

Comment: Oh ok I'm a noob when it comes to asp.net development. The example I was looking at from here showed both lines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your own buttons. It's done automatically by "FileUpload"

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm still new to ASP.NET development and the tutorial here showed both: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The FileUpload Control includes a path box (not visible in Chrome) and a Browse button (Choose File in Chrome) to choose the file. In general you don't need to have 2 buttons for upload ("Load XML", "Load XSL"). You can have just one button and upload 2 files together from multiple FileUpload controls.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thanks. I'm new at ASP.NET development and the tutorial here showed both: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx